# How to make Text widget non resizable when changing a Text size by mouse wheel?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

When I try to scroll text in Text widget mousehweel also resize widget itself. But I just need to resize text inside.

```
import tkinter as tk


def on_mouse_wheel(event):
    # Increase or decrease the font size based on mouse wheel rotation
    if event.delta > 0:
        current_font_size = int(text_widget['font'].split()[1])
        text_widget.config(font=("Arial", current_font_size + 2))
    else:
        current_font_size = int(text_widget['font'].split()[1])
        text_widget.config(font=("Arial", current_font_size - 2))


root = tk.Tk()

text_widget = tk.Text(root, font=("Arial", 12),
                      wrap=tk.NONE)  # Set wrap to NONE
text_widget.pack(expand=True,
                 fill='both')  # Make the Text widget fill the available space

# Add a horizontal scrollbar
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal', command=text_widget.xview)
scrollbar.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
text_widget['xscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

# Bind the mouse wheel event to the on_mouse_wheel function
text_widget.bind("<MouseWheel>", on_mouse_wheel)

root.mainloop()
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `Text` widget into a containing `Frame`, then set the dimensions of that frame how you want them and set `pack_propagate(False)` on the frame to prevent it from resizing as you change the font size.

I also added `text_widget.see('end')` to your mousewheel callback so the end of the text is always in view as you update the font size.

```
import tkinter as tk


def on_mouse_wheel(event):
    # Increase or decrease the font size based on mouse wheel rotation
    if event.delta > 0:
        current_font_size = int(text_widget['font'].split()[1])
        text_widget.config(font=("Arial", current_font_size + 2))
    else:
        current_font_size = int(text_widget['font'].split()[1])
        text_widget.config(font=("Arial", current_font_size - 2))
    # make sure the end of the text is always visible on size updates
    text_widget.see('end')


root = tk.Tk()
# create a frame to contain the text box (set width and height as desired)
container = tk.Frame(root, width=480, height=240)
container.pack_propagate(False)  # prevent the frame from resizing
container.pack(fill='both')
# set the text_widget's parent to 'container' here instead of 'root'
text_widget = tk.Text(container, font=("Arial", 12),
                      wrap=tk.NONE)  # Set wrap to NONE
text_widget.pack(expand=True,
                 fill='both')  # Make the Text widget fill the available space

# Add a horizontal scrollbar
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal', command=text_widget.xview)
scrollbar.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
text_widget['xscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

# Bind the mouse wheel event to the on_mouse_wheel function
text_widget.bind("<MouseWheel>", on_mouse_wheel)

root.mainloop()
```